# Having problems with Recently Viewed Product Thumbnail. Is there something wrong with my CSS code or a code I can use?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, product

Our recently viewed products are positioned via landscape and the product photo is warped. As well as the product category on the left? Would really like to place it together by row. Is there anything wrong with the CSS code? Thank you for the help!

Here's the website link: http://aom.sg/product-category/air/

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZGkl.png)

Comment: You need to provide some code so we cant help you with your problem , please take a moment and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your products are set in 5 columns. To display them in row, you need to make some changes in CSS:

For example in large screens the CSS to add in your theme styles.css file, for product category archive pages, will be:

```css
.woocommerce.tax-product_cat ul.products li.product, 
.woocommerce-page.tax-product_cat ul.products li.product {
    width: 19% !important;
    margin-right: 1% !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .woocommerce.tax-product_cat ul.products li.product, 
    .woocommerce-page.tax-product_cat ul.products li.product, 
    .woocommerce-page.tax-product_cat[class*=columns-] ul.products li.product,
    .woocommerce.tax-product_cat[class*=columns-] ul.products li.product {
        width: 46% !important;
        margin-right: 4% !important;
        margin-left: 0 !important;
    }
}
```

This should work.

For other screen devices, you should need to find out, the correct overriding CCS rules, using your browser code inspector…

Comment: Hello! This worked for the desktop version but for mobile it's not aligned well. Could you give me a sample code to cater for mobile as well? Sorry I'm not really good at coding. Will really appreciate the help.

Comment: Thanks for the patience, LoicTheAztec! This worked! But it made the subcategory page looked portrait rather than landscape after clicking a certain product category.  TT

Link: http://aom.sg/product-category/air/airdisinfect/

Comment: @Zeth I have a complete answer related to your problems… So ask a **new question** with this title **"change the display on "sub sub product category pages in WooCommerce"**. You should include the css rules from this answer *(to avoid down votes and closing)*,  explaining what they are doing, adding the link from your shop and the link for your sub sub categories… Then add a screenshot of what you are expecting (just like before applying this CSS)… Once done notify me here. If needed you can contact me on skype chat, my Id is `marsloic`.